# How exactly would i get multiple clients to be able to connect here?

Tags: python, networking

This is the client:

```
import socket
import threading

username = input("enter username: ")
ip = input("enter ip: ")
port = int(input("enter port: "))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))
user_encode = bytes(username, "utf-8")
s.send(b"\n" + user_encode + b" has joined the room!")


def send():
    while True:
        message = input("")
        encode = bytes(message, "utf-8")
        s.send(user_encode + b": " + encode)


def receive():
    while True:
        receive_msg = s.recv(2048)
        decode = receive_msg.decode()
        print(decode)


sending = threading.Thread(target=send, daemon=False)
receiving = threading.Thread(target=receive, daemon=False)
sending.start()
receiving.start()
```

this is the server:

```
import socket
import threading
import selectors

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
port = int(input("enter port: "))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ip, port))
print(f"listening on {ip}")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()


def transfer():
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv(2048)
        conn.sendall(msg)


def commands():
    while True:
        print("Enter server commands")
        cmd = input(">> ")
        if cmd == "sendmessage":
            what_message = input("what to send? ")
            encode_message = bytes(what_message, "utf-8")
            conn.sendall(b"Server owner: "+encode_message)


message = threading.Thread(target=transfer, daemon=False)
server_cmd = threading.Thread(target=commands, daemon=False)
message.start()
server_cmd.start()
```

how would i get this to be a server where multiple clients could connect? i am rather new to sockets

The server and client both WORK, but it's not really a chatroom if people can't chat.
If a new client connects, it just doesn't register

Comment: You should have a main thread that's in a loop calling `s.accept()`. Whenever a connection comes in, it spawns a new thread to serve it.

Comment: i tried to make one that spawns another server listening thread for the new user on connect, but it does not work at all. everything just breaks
if clients try to talk, the one that was there first just gets blank space spammed all over the terminal, and half of the messages don't go through

Comment: You shouldn't spawn a listening thread, spawn a worker thread.

Comment: The connection should be an argument to the worker thread's function.

Comment: Do you want multiple clients connected at the same time?  or one after the other?